# Why smtplib.SMTP not working properly in python?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

***This is the program:***

````
`import smtplib, ssl

`receiver = 'receiver@example.com'`

`username = "sender@example.com"`
`password = " "`

`message = """`
`Subject: hi`
`how are you?`
`"""`
`context = ssl.create_default_context()`

`with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.google.com', port=465, context=context) as server:`
`    server.login(username, password)`
`    server.sendmail(username, receiver, message)```
````

**Error:**

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhijay/py/proj2-portfolio/se.py", line 14, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host='smtp.google.com', port=465, context=context) as server:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 1056, in _get_socket
    new_socket = super()._get_socket(host, port, timeout)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**i was trying to send email, but it keeps on showing the above error.I have no idea what to do
tried few things, which i found on internet but nothing worked.**

Comment: The traceback says that you pressed Ctrl-C to stop the program.  Did you?  And you should be using port 587, not 465.

Comment: Both ports are OK (587 for startls, 465 for SSL), but the domain is `smtp.gmail.com` (not google.com)

Comment: Thank you both, Tim Roberts and VPfB, i made a few mistakes. But now it is working.